# PHP - Paypal ExpressCheckout change session_id

Tags: php, paypal, checkout

i know there are many people out there having problems with paypal checkout but i really can't find some help for my problem…

i'm using paypal in **sandbox** mode, without problems paypal recieve all of the information incl. TAX, SHIPPING etc. , on the paypal side i log in with my *sandbox* PayPalAcc confirm the buying via creditcard click continue…

**here is the problem**

after re-direct from paypal it says "NO ORDER TOTAL" and my session_id() is a complete other *id* than before.

i'm looking @the path in browser so there is no problem with the *www.* or something.
and also funny is that if i got the other session_id() & cart_items says zero items now and i click in the shop on the *product* i want to buy before it restores my session_id() automatically and says 1 item in cart and the session_id() is the same as before i click checkout on first redirect to paypal..

maybe there is a problem how i connected the sites.

There is shop.php inside of shop i "include" the other sites also the cart.php & from there i connect to the script paypal-process.php -> PAYPAL -> redirect to paypal-process.php…

i'm new at using sessions so pls don't blame me :D

**thanks**

Comment: Are you switching back and forth between http and https by chance?

Comment: my url to paypal look like this:
$paypalurl ='https://www'.$paypalmode.'.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token='.$httpParsedResponseArgument["TOKEN"].'';

$getSessionID = session_id();
can i send the session id to paypal using &session=$getSessionID
and paypal send me than the paypal-success.php?token=EC-xxxxxxxxxx&PayerID=xxxxxx&session=MYFIRSTSESSIONID

is that what you mean?

Comment: What are you using for your return URL?  Are you using an http:// address or an https:// address?  Whichever it is, is that what you're starting with? It sounds like maybe you're starting at http://www.domain.com but then getting returned to https://www.domain.com/return/, in which case you would lose your sessions.

Comment: thank you for quick response 

maybe i can send the sessionid with using: &PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTREQUESTID=/*SESSIONID*/
in process….anyway you're right but why i lose the session and the better question is why i get it back after i click a product to view not even click on add to cart

Comment: Sessions are separate for http:// vs https://.  Sounds like you're starting with http://, getting returned to https://, but then when you click the product it's taking you to http:// again, which would still have the original session.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71396/discussion-between-steve-krew-and-andrew-angell).

Comment: thanks for your help i found the catch!